# Printing out xml data in Python?

Tags: python, xml, soap

I am trying to call a web service that returns me the Database Connection String using Python. I need to print out a specific data from the xml and store it in a string. How do i do it?

```
import requests

url="http://172.10.3.2:8250/GS/GetConnectionStrings.asmx?WSDL"
#headers = {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml'}
headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
body = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                            <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
                              <soap:Body>
                                <DatabaseConnectionString xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'>
                                  <DatabaseName>ELMA</DatabaseName>
                                </DatabaseConnectionString>
                              </soap:Body>
                            </soap:Envelope>"""

response = requests.post(url,data=body,headers=headers)
print response.content
```

The result is printed as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body><DatabaseConnectionStringResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <DatabaseConnectionStringResult>Data Source=172.10.3.3;Initial Catalog=Elma;User ID=User11021969;Password=ILoveMyMOM;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=5000;Connect Timeout=180;Application Name=ElmaMobileCommerce
</DatabaseConnectionStringResult>
</DatabaseConnectionStringResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need to print out the following specifically and store it in a string ;-

```
<DatabaseConnectionStringResult>Data Source=172.10.3.3;Initial Catalog=Elma;User ID=User11021969;Password=ILoveMyMOM;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=5000;Connect Timeout=180;Application Name=ElmaMobileCommerce</DatabaseConnectionStringResult>
```

Comment: The easiest way seems to be to search for substrings `<soap:Body>` and `</soap:Body>` and print the substring in the middle - and if you can't find them both, to print there was no result. Is there anything that can happen and may crash that algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(body)
print root[0][0][0].text
```

The output looks like this

```
Data Source=172.10.3.3;Initial Catalog=Elma;User ID=User11021969;Password=ILoveMyMOM;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=5000;Connect Timeout=180;Application Name=ElmaMobileCommerce
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've done using lxml

```python
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True, remove_comments=True)
root = etree.fromstring(body, parser=parser)
elem = root.find(".//{http://tempuri.org/}DatabaseConnectionStringResult")
xmlstr = etree.tostring(elem)
```

output:

```xml
<DatabaseConnectionStringResult xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">Data Source=172.10.3.3;Initial Catalog=Elma;User ID=User11021969;Password=ILoveMyMOM;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=5000;Connect Timeout=180;Application Name=ElmaMobileCommerce\n</DatabaseConnectionStringResult>
```

Variation:

```
etree.tostring(elem, method='text')
```

will output:

```
Data Source=172.10.3.3;Initial Catalog=Elma;User ID=User11021969;Password=ILoveMyMOM;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=5000;Connect Timeout=180;Application Name=ElmaMobileCommerce
```

edit -- updated to pull out only the DatabaseConnectionStringResult